# Fetch BackboneJS model from id (I think)

Tags: javascript, caching, grails, backbone.js, local-storage

I'm responsible to make a cache-layer, that uses local storage, that is between the server and the client to lower the bandwidth and server load.

I have two models, 'model' and 'modelContent'. These are connected to each other with an ID.
model is populated as it should be with all the parameters that are in the model.
modelContent is not populated when its content is fully fetched from the server.

I want to wait until the modelContent has it's attribute 'body' fully populated and then add it to the cache. Right now modelContent's 'body'-attribute is just an empty string (which is the default value).

I have created a base-model that model and modelContent inherits from that contains an override for sync for the read-method. The reason for this is that I read http://engineering.linkedin.com/mobile/linkedin-ipad-using-local-storage-snappy-mobile-apps and that is the way I want it to work but with two models that belong together.

I'm very new at BackboneJS and Grails (which the project uses as well) so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

My base-model:

```
var basic_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
    if ( method === 'read' ) {
      uid = this.get("UID");
      if ( uid ) {
        var success = options.success;
        options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
          console.log(resp);
        }
      } else {
        Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
      }
    } else {
      Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    }
}
```

modelContent:

```
var MailContentItem = basic_model.extend({
  urlRoot: project_webroot +'modelContent',

  idAttribute: "UID",

  defaults: function() {
    return _.extend({}, basic_model.prototype.defaults, {
      isHTML: false,
      body: ""
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you run this in the debugger and verify that you're calling `Backbone.sync` at least once?  Without doing so your model won't have the data.

Comment: @dylants How do I run the debugger?

Comment: Using Chrome, while viewing your page that has the Backbone logic within it, right click on the page and select "Inspect Element".  Switch to the "Sources" tab and place a breakpoint within your code.  Refresh the page to reload the actions.  You should be able to see what is happening by stepping through the code.  Here's a link to Chrome's help page on using their debugger: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging